# WSDL has the wrong URL in the soap:address location Magento

Tags: magento, iis, soap, magento-1.9

I am working on Magento Soap API version 2. but During login call I am getting site complete index page HTML instead of valid data.

After Debug using Soap UI I have found that soap:address location URL is incorrect.

**URL Coming:**  `http://SITENAME/index.php/?type=v2_soap` 
**Correct URL:**  `http://SITENAME/api/v2_soap/?wsdl=1`

I have checked in wsdl xml as well. It have default values there.

Anyone face the same issue ? Please Help !!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?  I think I've got the same problem.

Comment: To be honest .. its very long time, I am not able to remind. I will check if I find something useful, I will share with you

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't change anything in Magento's code you should use this URL:

[`https://yourmagentosite.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/`](https://yourmagentosite.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/)

if it will not work, try to use: [`https://yourmagentosite.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/`](https://yourmagentosite.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/)

Also, keep in mind that some url may not work due to incorrect web server configuration, in this way you should look into web server config.